# How to create associative hashs in Ruby (on Rails) dynamicly

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am developing a webapp with Ruby on Rails to expand the features of [mite](http://mite.yo.lk) (online time-tracking app) with the help of the offical mite API. Unfortuanaly, the API can't return all projects by a specific customer id. Because of that, i am developing a workaround.

At first, i get all customers and save them in a hash. Then i iterate throug all projects and save each project object to a hash inside the customer hash.

My code looks like this:

```
def index
  # Mite authentication
  Mite.account = '...'
  Mite.authenticate('...','...')

  # get all customers from Mite
  @customers = Hash.new
  Mite::Customer.all.each do |customer|
    @customers[customer.id] = {:name => customer.name, :projects => Hash.new}
  end

  # get all projects from Mite
  Mite::Project.all.each do |project|
    @customers[project.customer_id][:projects] = {:project => project}
  end
end
```

Unfortuanaly, only the last project is saved in the ":projects" hash. But why? Adding customers works with this method too. In general, is this "the ruby way"? I'm very new to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save projects in array or something like it, not hash. For example

```
  Mite::Customer.all.each do |customer|
    @customers[customer.id] = {:name => customer.name, :projects => []} # !!!
  end

  Mite::Project.all.each do |project|
    @customers[project.customer_id][:projects] << project # !!!
  end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :)
But can you explain WHY i have to use an array and not a hash?

Comment: Actually you can use and array and hash (but array imho more convenient in your case). When you use hash you need unique keys for every value (but now you use not unique key :project and every time update value for this key). So if you want to use hash you need write: @customers[project.customer_id][:projects][project.id] = project